# Retain Two Dependent Dropdowns selected values after form submit or page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to have my two dependent dropdowns selected options to stay selected after client submit/refresh page.

1- I want my validation to be Client-side not Server-side.

2- I have my dropdown values in an array using a **Script** not with **HTML Select** and **Option** Tags **+ PhP** method.

3- I currently achieved making dropdown **B** content dependent on dropdown **A** selection by User so no problem with that.

4- I just don't know how to do it with the **Script** method instead of using **PhP** tags after every **Option** tag (because that way it took a lot of coding to achieve something simple in theory as this :S).

5- I'm asking this question because i believe there must be a way to do it with a **Script** if I'm not mistaking :D so please correct me if there is no other way than writing it like this:

```
<option value="test" <?php if(isset($_POST["sign-up"]) && $_POST["province"]=="test") { echo " selected"; } ?>>test</option>
```

Currently This is my Code:

```js
var provinceObject = {
  "province1": {
    "1city1p1": [1],
    "1city2p1": [2],
    "1city3p1": [3]
  },
  "province2": {
    "2city1p2": [4],
    "2city2p2": [5],
    "2city3p2": [6]
  },
  "province3": {
    "3city1p3": [7],
    "3city2p3": [8],
    "3city3p3": [9]
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var provinceSel = document.getElementById("province");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("city");

  for (var x in provinceObject) {
    provinceSel.options[provinceSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  provinceSel.onchange = function() {
    citySel.length = 1;
    for (var y in provinceObject[this.value]) {
      citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="SignUpForm" id="SignUpForm">

  <TABLE frame="box">
    <TR>
      <TD dir="rtl" style="text-align: center"><b>province</b></TD>
      <TD>
        <select name="province" id="province">
          <option value="1" selected>select your province</option>
        </select>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <!--=========================================================================================-->
    <TR>
      <TD dir="rtl" style="text-align: center"><b>city</b></TD>
      <TD>
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="1" selected>select your city</option>
        </select>

      </TD>
    </TR>
    <!--=========================================================================================-->
    <p>
      <INPUT style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; background-color: mediumseagreen; 
    color: darkred" type="submit" NAME="sign-up" ID="sign-up" value="submit">

    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: **I want to** is not a question. It just informs us that you want us to do the heavy lifting for you.
Where are you stuck? What have you researched? What have you tried? To be clear, we'll help you at stackoverflow but we're not a free do-my-thinking service 
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you need to look at ajax methods and validation techniques in html5

Comment: Of course there are other ways. If PHP can create the necessary HTML code dynamically on the server side - then JavaScript can do the same thing on the client side. But that is not even necessary here - you are already using the `Option` constructor, and that takes more parameters, than just the two you are currently passing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

Comment: So you just need to combine this now with some logic that stores the user's current selection in `localStorage`, and reads it back from there, when the page loads. And if you find data in there on page load - then you mark the corresponding options as selected, the very moment you create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage

uncomment the localStorage statements below and remove the hardcode on your server

Note I use eventListeners and trigger the change event

I also updated your loading of the selects to code from this decade ;)

```js
var provinceObject = {
  "province1": {
    "1city1p1": [1],
    "1city2p1": [2],
    "1city3p1": [3]
  },
  "province2": {
    "2city1p2": [4],
    "2city2p2": [5],
    "2city3p2": [6]
  },
  "province3": {
    "3city1p3": [7],
    "3city2p3": [8],
    "3city3p3": [9]
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
  var provinceSel = document.getElementById("province");
  var citySel = document.getElementById("city");
  provinceSel.addEventListener("change",function() {
    citySel.length = 1;
    const provObj = provinceObject[this.value];
    if (!provObj) return 
    const prov = Object.keys(provObj);
    citySel.innerHTML += prov.map(city => `<option value="${city}">${city}</option>`).join("")
    // localStorage.setItem("province",this.value)
  })
  citySel.addEventListener("change",function() {
    // localStorage.setItem("city",this.value)
  })
  
  provinceSel.innerHTML += Object.keys(provinceObject).map(prov => `<option value="${prov}">${prov}</option>`).join("")
  const province = "province2" // localStorage.getItem("province")
  if (province) {
     provinceSel.value = province;
     provinceSel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
     const city = "2city2p2" // localStorage.getItem("city")
     citySel.value = city;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<form method="post" name="SignUpForm" id="SignUpForm">

  <TABLE frame="box">
    <TR>
      <TD dir="rtl" style="text-align: center"><b>province</b></TD>
      <TD>
        <select name="province" id="province">
          <option value="1" selected>select your province</option>
        </select>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <!--=========================================================================================-->
    <TR>
      <TD dir="rtl" style="text-align: center"><b>city</b></TD>
      <TD>
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="1" selected>select your city</option>
        </select>

      </TD>
    </TR>
    <!--=========================================================================================-->
    <p>
      <INPUT style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; background-color: mediumseagreen; 
    color: darkred" type="submit" NAME="sign-up" ID="sign-up" value="submit">

    </p>

</form>
```